LiFEpo4 issues and concern
I have a 200AH LiFEpo4 battery and I bought an inverter, my inverter has 4 output AC socket if I connected the 1st socket to  airconditioneer and and the 2nd socket to the charger continue charging the battery does it works perfectly?

Are you asking can you charge your battery from an inverter connected to the battery?  No, that is just a complicated heater.

If this is what you intend to do then NO, it won't work.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
